# Custom binding to return the last Json record

Tags: json, knockout.js

I'm using the following code to load all Json data.

```
    $.getJSON("/Home/GetSortedLists", function (allData) {
        var mappedSortedLists = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new SortedLists(item) });
        viewModel.sortedlists(mappedSortedLists);
    });
```

I also need to load a single record from the same Json data; the record with the highest SortedListsID value (i.e. the last record entered).

Can anybody suggest the best way to do this? I've considered adding `viewModel.lastsortedlist` and amending the above code somehow. I've also considered creating a `last` custom binding to do something like:

```
<tbody data-bind="last: sortedlists.SortedListID">
```

All advice welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to do more ui-related stuff with the record, I don't think you need the custom binding.

It should be enough to compute it in the getJSON callback and save it in the viewModel:

```
       $.getJSON("/Home/GetSortedLists", function (allData) {
            var mappedSortedLists = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new SortedLists(item) });
            viewModel.sortedlists(mappedSortedLists);
            //correct the sort function if it's bad, or drop it if allData is already sorted
            var sortedData = allData.sort(function(a,b){ return a.SortedListID - b.SortedListID}) 
            viewModel.lastSortedList(sortedData[sortedData.length - 1])
        });
```

Or, if it can change outside the getJSON callback, you could also make it a computed observable:

```
viewModel.lastSortedList = ko.computed(function(){
                //correct the sort function if it's bad, or drop it
                var sortedData = mappedSortedLists().sort(function(a,b){ return a.SortedListID - b.SortedListID}) 
                return sortedData[sortedData.length - 1]
}, this)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I haven't got this working yet but will persist. What your solution proposes is that the Json data is sorted by ID and then the last item of the array is returned. Is that a better approach than to traverse the array and return the ID with the greatest value without performing a sort? Is it also a better approach than using server-side Linq to return the Json item as well as using Linq to return the full dataset?

Comment: No, you can do it either way. It's up to you.

Comment: Okay, thanks. May I ask for an example of traversing the array for the highest value ID? Or at least advice how to approach it? Thanks again.

Comment: Great - I've tried to expand on that to display the maxId using ArrayFirst. http://jsfiddle.net/FZ6K6/3/ I'm still not quite there though. Am I getting close?

Comment: Yup, you're almost there. You need to make a computed observable to have it update every time the array changes. Here's an updated working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FZ6K6/4/